# Need Extjs Simple Login code

Tags: extjs

need extjs code for login. if username="admin" & password="admin" open new panel else show error alert. Please Help me. thanks in advance

```
  buttons: [{
            text: 'Login',
        handler:function(){
            simple.getForm().reset();
            }
        //handler:loginclk
        /** var usnme=Ext.getCmp('usr').getValue();
        var pswd=Ext.getCmp('ped').getValue():
        if(usnme=='admin' && pswd=='admin'){
            Ext.MessageBox.show({Fine});
            }
            else { Ext.MessageBox.show({wrong });
            }

        handler : function() {
            if(uname=="admin" && pwd=="admin"){
                window.redirect();
        }
```

I Tried these two codes but it doesn.t works

Answer (score 0):

Ext.MessageBox.show() takes a config object, you are passing in undefined variables Fine and wrong.

Instead:

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({text: 'Fine'});
```

You must be seeing errors in your console too?

This handler code should work for you:

```
handler : function() {
    var usnme=Ext.getCmp('usr').getValue();
    var pwd=Ext.getCmp('ped').getValue():
    if(uname=="admin" && pwd=="admin"){
            window.redirect();
    } else {
        Ext.MessageBox.show({text:'Wrong'});
    }
}
```

Provided the id's you have assigned to your inputs are correct 'usr' and 'ped'